# asp.net - set master page form ID dynamically

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I am working on a site which uses master pages (no big deal), and has a form in the master page.

Currently, the form name in the rendered content is always "aspnetform".

I need to change some of the pages that use this master page, and I need to set the form name to something specific for that page (for SEO reasons).

Is there a simple way to do this, in the pages that use the master page?

NOTE: I'm not changing all of the pages that use the master, so the master page really should not change; no rearchitecture.

Comment: Can I ask why you think the id of the Form element on the page is that important to SEO? I've dealt with a number of SEO consultants on our sites, and not one has ever mentioned the id's of our elements - seeing as even metadata plays less of a role to most engines, I'm skeptical as to the benefits.

Comment: Good question.  I don't personally care myself; the implementation is cross platform (a number of LAMP and .NET sites), and is implemented using the Form ID.  A requirement is to conform to this agreement.  The javascript layer looks at the Form.  I understand the question and concur with the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some consideration, I decided to remove the usage of the master file from the pages I needed to change.
Not ideal, but the easiest solution.

Research which led me to this solution:
http://forums.asp.net/t/899152.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://forums.asp.net/p/883974/929349.aspx) may help you out, though it seems that there's troubles with Designer mode with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override UniqueID in the master page. This is returning aspnetForm by default.